# Trying to Pass Column Names to R Function That Uses ggplot2

Tags: r, function, ggplot2

I'm trying to build a custom function that will quickly output a scatterplot with ggplot2. This is my current code.

```
quick.scatter <- function(x, y) {

  # Plot
  ggplot(data = train, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
    geom_point()

}
```

When I try running this code, for example quick.scatter(quality, price), I get errors "object 'quality' not found". When I use df$quality, it works, but I don't want to do that. I can't seem to find a solution for this on here. How can I get the function to solely read the column names alone?

Comment: this already exists in ggplot: `qplot(x, y, data=train)`

Comment: More to the point, you'll want to google around and read about the function `aes_string()`. That's the easy way, or you can google and read about quasiquotation, which is newly supported in ggplot2, but quite a bit harder to understand.

Comment: I always had problems with building ggplot related functions. This explanation helped me : http://www.onceupondata.com/2018/07/06/ggplot-tidyeval/